# Closable AdMob with Sencha Touch + Cordova

Tags: cordova, sencha-touch, admob, ads

I'm using Sencha Touch + Cordova on an app, I'm also using Cordova's AdMob Google Plugin (https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-admob-pro/tree/master/doc) to display a banner on the bottom of my app, but the thing is it's tremendously annoying (it does it's job well), but I want to give the user a chance to close that add.

Is there any way of adding a button like on the right top corner of the add to close it?

I've gone through the Cordova plugin API Reference and there seems to be no mention of this, but I figured someone must have done this somewhere.

**EDIT**

Either that or an "elegant" way to resize my app's view to fit the app itself and the banner.

**EDIT 2**

I've learnt that placing an X on top or above the add is not a good idea as it goes against some of the policies that AdMob has, so that's a no-go. I will however need to resize my app's view to fit the banner without overlapping any buttons.
I will create another question as the title is misleading but will leave this in here in case someone comes up with any idea.

Answer (score 0):

The admob plugin, or AdMob SDK, does not offer a "X" button on Ad to close the banner view.

You need implement that by your own to show a button or X, when event (user click it) triggered, call the method:

```
window.plugins.AdMob.showAd(false);
```

But, in your web app (html5 or javascript), you cannot put a button or X onto the banner, as the banner view is not a DOM element, but a separate native view.

Maybe, you can set it as an option in your settings, if you have a settings page.